# Using email templates where targetobjectid is user

Tags: email, batch, html

Objects: Obj1 and Obj2. Obj2 is child of Obj1. Obj1 has a lookup to user object(User__c).
I have a batch class wherein i am trying to schedule emails. I want to use an HTML email template. The template has the following content

Dear {!Obj2.Resource_name__c}

Please click on below link 
{!Obj2.Link}

In the batch code , I have set the targetobjectid to User__c . Then i have set the whatid to Obj2.id. But i am getting an error saying whatid cannot be set if targetobjectid is user. 
What is the solution to this?

Comment: Can you use Contacts instead?

Comment: No there is no reference to contacts in the data model